# How to include uncompiled java files in a JAR built by Tycho?

Tags: maven, tycho

I have a source root with *.java files, but I don't want them to be compiled. Instead, the *.java files should be copied into the jar as they are. The use case for this is that the *.java files are templates and hence should be preserved as they are.

To achieve this, I tried to exclude a source folder from compiling phase of my build and I am quite confused by the official documentation to the Tycho OSGi Compiler Plugin. It says I can use parameter [excludeResources](https://eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#excludeResources) but I don't really know how to handle all these parameter types. `pom.xml` is a structured text file and not a source file, that's why I don't understand how to use `java.util.Set` for that parameter.

My POM goes like this:

```xml
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.21.0</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <excludeResources>
                    <!-- Set of folders consisting of a source folder named "res"
                         which should be excluded completely from compilation -->
                </excludeResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Is it a right approach? If yes, how would I complete the configuration?

Comment: it's not clear from your question whether you want to exclude a whole source root folder or just a package inside a source root folder from compilation. Also, do you want to exclude *.java files from compilation or resources (non-java files) from being copied?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I specified my question more precisely.

Comment: @Danny: Your edit made the question better, but it is even better to start with your goals, and only then state what you tried. Especially since it is questionable whether you were on the right track with the tycho-compiler-plugin at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude a whole source root folder from compilation, simply do not add it to any of the src.* entries in build.properties, see [1]

If on the other hand you want to include the *.java files in the source root folder in the resulting jar, add the root folder to the list of bin.includes in build.properties.

excludeResources is unrelated to your problem, as the docs you linked say:

"A list of exclusion filters for non-java resource files which should not be copied to the output directory."

[1] http://eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/BuildProperties.html

Comment: I think that this is the correct answer, but it would be more useful if it included an example for the proposed build.properties changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to remove any occurences of "res" folder and files:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho-version}</version>
        <configuration>
                <excludeResources>
                        <excludeResource>**/res</excludeResource>
                </excludeResources>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

or this, alternatively, for example, to include the "res" folder and exclude .jar files:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho-version}</version>
        <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>res</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.jar</exclude>
                </excludes>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Or, to exclude everything that is not the "res" folder:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho-version}</version>
        <configuration>
                <excludeResources>
                        <excludeResource>!**/res</excludeResource>
                </excludeResources>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: How do i know to use `<excludeResource/>` to build a set of `<excludeResources>`? It is logical and straight forward of course, but not really worth to figure it out by try and error. Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: You can add as many rules as you like:

<excludeResources>

   <excludeResource>rule 1</excludeResource>

   <excludeResource>rule 2</excludeResource>

</excludeResources>


You can find this documented in the official page that you link in the opening post, and in online tutorials such as http://mukis.de/pages/maven-tycho-java-scala-and-apt/ and http://larsschuetze.wordpress.com/2014/07/30/from-handmade-to-automatic-introducing-tycho-for-eclipse-rcp-applications/

Comment: Since tycho is very new, there is lack of some documentation aspects. You are not alone in this issue. Tycho needs to mature its documentation.

Comment: @ManelJ: Tycho is an open-source project, so step up and constribute. Actually, even a bug report with what specifically is lacking documentation would help. Just posting here that the project needs to do something is not helpful.

Comment: oberlie: I fully agree with you. Unfortunately, given my technical knowledge I am not able to contribute to this specific project other than reporting issues from a user perspective.